# Extract data from "p" html element with python lxml

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I want to extract all the data in the `p` `html` elements, but to treat differently only to the "headers" such as: `<strong>header1</strong>`.
Is there a way to do it with `python` `lxml`?
With the following code:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser(target=MyParser())
etree.HTML(htmlContent, parser)
```

Whilst `class MyParser` is:

```
class MyParser(object):
    def start(self, tag, attrib):
        pass
    def end(self, tag):
        pass
    def data(self, data):
        --> Here, differentiate between "normal data" and <strong>data</strong>
    def close(self):
        pass
```

`html` Example:

```
<div class="entry-content clearfix">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>header1</strong></span>:<br />
        data data 1...</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>header2</strong></span>:<br />
        data data 2...</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>header3</strong></span>:<br />
        data data 3...<br />
        data data 3...<br />
        data data 3...</p>
</div>
```

Example of what I want to do:
Lets say I aggregate all of the data in a `string`, and I want to highlight only the headers.
Now I cannot differentiate, so my string would be like:

```
header1 data data data 1... header2 data data data 2...
```

I want to highlight it like, so it would be like this:

```
[[header1]] data data data 1... [[header2]] data data data 2...
```

Comment: What does `but to treat differently only to the "headers" such as: <strong>header1</strong>` mean? Can you explain a little more please?

Comment: Could you show what the expected result from your sample input would be, at least?

Comment: Lets say I aggregate all of the data in a `string`, and I want to highlight only the headers. Now I cannot differentiate, so my string would be like: `header1 data data data 1... header2 data data data 2...`. I want to highlight it like this: `[[header1]] data data data 1... [[header2]] data data data 2...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to implement your class `MyParser`.

When the start tag for an element is seen, push it on a stack.  When the end tag for the element is seen pop it off the stack.  When data is received you will know what tag you are in: the top one on the stack.  The state machine pattern is often applicable to such parsing needs.

Comment: The problem is that I can't differentiate the data inside the tag. How can I know what is `<strong>header1</strong>` and what is not?

Comment: @hudac:  I described how you can know what is in a 'strong' tag and what isn't.  What have you tried so far?  Do you have any code in the methods of `MyParser`?  What parts of that class do you understand and what parts don't you understand?

Comment: Thanks, I thought I can't see `strong` tag in there, but I can.